# Where to copy a file so I can open it from GWT Eclipse Google Plugin in dev mode?

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin, jetty

I'm learning GWT with Google Eclipse Plugin, and I want to use some configuration file (generatorConfig.xml) from my server code, how do I upload it to the default devmode server? how do I open it from my Java code?

I've put the generatorConfig.xml file in the war/WEB-INF/deploy/[my app]/ but I can't open it...

```
String line;
BufferedReader in;

in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("generatorConfig.xml"));
line = in.readLine();
```

I get this stack trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: generatorConfig.xml (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at bo.rowen.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem including the file in the src folder and loading just with the file name, (my file now is named configuration.xml):

```
String resource = "configuration.xml";
try {
    reader    = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
    sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image: This is how it looks in my Eclipse IDE...]

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in `/war/WEB-INF/` folder. Then you can:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/generatorConfig.xml");
```

Comment: I've put it there, using the left panel in Eclipse, it still complains with the same stack trace (I've correctly refreshed the server)